# Symfony Console - Doctrine Generate Proxies

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I have a problem with generating entity proxies directly to a folder.

I have configured a proxy dir and a proxy namespace, but whenever I run
`orm:generate:proxies` command it pushes the output to the console, instead of outputting class code.

```
$config->setProxyDir('path');
$config->setProxyNamespace('DoctrineEntitiesProxies');
```

The funny thing is, it generates proxies automatically, to the correct folder, but when I run the command with the same instance of entity manager it pushes the output like I said before, to the console.

When I run `orm:generate:proxies /tmp`, it still stays the same. Output goes to the console.

So the question is, if I am doing it wrong and how to do it right then?

PS. I am using Symfony 2.1

Comment: I think it will be hard for most people here to help you with a SF 2.1 project, as SF 2.1 is obsolete. The `orm:generate:proxies` command doesn't even exist anymore (SF 2.3).